# How to turn off selenium console logging in java using FirefoxDriver?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to turn off the logger in eclipse while using the selenium web driver.

```
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();       
    profile.setPreference("webdriver.log.driver", "ERROR");

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

while running the program, i'm still getting these debug logs:

```
[DEBUG] 2015-04-10 12:10:39,904
CookieSpec selected: best-match

[DEBUG] 2015-04-10 12:10:39,922
Auth cache not set in the context

[DEBUG] 2015-04-10 12:10:39,925
Connection request: [route: {}->http://127.0.0.1:7056][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 2000; total allocated: 0 of 2000]

[DEBUG] 2015-04-10 12:10:39,960
Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {}->http://127.0.0.1:7056][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 2000; total allocated: 1 of 2000]

[DEBUG] 2015-04-10 12:10:39,969
Opening connection {}->http://127.0.0.1:7056
```

Is there any way to turn them off?

Comment: What are the levels set for LogType.DRIVER and LogType.CLIENT in your case?

Comment: i did not set any of them.. should i?

Comment: Just check what are the levels. It shouldn't be debug by default in fact.

Comment: @Stanjer where do i check it?

Comment: Had to change the from log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout, R  to log4j.rootLogger=info, stdout, R

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable log trace in Marionette driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37803781/disable-log-trace-in-marionette-driver)